# How do you formally justify using limits on an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Example: Let $f$ be continuous at $c$, and let $m_h = \inf \{ f(x) : c \le x \le c + h \}, M_h = \sup \{ f(x) : c \le x \le c + h \}$. Then $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0} m_h = \displaystyle\lim_{h\to0} M_h = f(c)$, but what is the formal justification for this?

Really, what we have is an interval $I = [c,c+h]$ and then $\lim_{h\to0} I = c$, correct? But still, this seems non-rigorous in the sense that the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit existing that I know of won't support taking the limit of an interval in that form. Of course, intuitively it makes sense.

But also, we don't necessarily require a closed interval. For example: The MVT states that if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b - a)$. Now when solving a certain problem in Spivak's Calculus, he used the fact that if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then for $x \le b$, $f(x) - f(a) = f'(\zeta)(x - a)$ for some $\zeta \in (a,x)$. Then he argued that as $x \to a$, $f'(\zeta) \to f'(a)$. But how does this make sense? $\zeta \in (a,x)$, so as $x \to a$, we get the interval approaching $(a,a)$.

Comment: You don't need "limits of intervals" to answer this question, and you don't need to go into the MVT to understand it. A straightforward proof using the definitions of continuity, of limits, and of infimums is certainly possible. Did you make any attempts in that direction?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, in the first example would want to show that $\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, 0 < |h| < \delta \implies |\inf \{ f(x) : c \le x \le c + h\} - f(c)| < \varepsilon$. If we let $\alpha$ be the infimum, then $\alpha \le f(c)$ by definition, so we want to show that $f(c) - \alpha < \varepsilon$. 

The point of my second example is that the open interval goes to $(a,a)$ and so MVT is not even satisfied!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $h \ge 0$.

Note that $m_h \in \mathbb{R}$. So actually,  we could write $g : \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0} \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$g(h) = \text{inf} \{f(x):c \le x \le c+h\}$$

There are no limits of intervals (although you can imagine that $g$ is related to a family of descending intervals). The limit can equivalently be written as $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h)$, where as noted, $g$ is a standard function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Similarly for $M_h$.

Hopefully, this answers your main question. With Spivak's proof, the issue is that:

$$x \to a, \; \zeta \in (a,x) \not \Rightarrow \zeta \in \lim_{x \to a} (a,x)$$

even if the limit on the RHS is/was well-defined. Again, we are only concerned with the limit of a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, which in this case is $f'$. We seek to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 $ such that:

$$|x - a| < \delta \implies |f'(\zeta)-f'(a)| < \varepsilon$$

(Or you could use an equivalent formulation in terms of sequences.)

In this case, there is a simpler way to do it:

$$f(x)-f(a)=(x-a)f'(\zeta)$$

$$\implies  f'(\zeta) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

$$\implies \lim_{x \to a} f'(\zeta) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

$$ \implies \lim_{x \to a} f'(\zeta) = f'(a)$$

Comment: But why doesn't it matter that $\zeta \in (a,x)\to(a,a)$ as $x \to a$?

Comment: @politeproofs It doesn't matter because it is not what Spivak claims in the proof. He writes $f'(\zeta) \to f(a)$ as $x \to a$, which is a statement about $f'$, not the interval $(a,x)$. Remember also that we can define limits $x \to a$ of a function $g$ even if $g(a)$ is not defined. Limits are about the behaviour *near* a certain point, not at the point.

Comment: But to even get the existence of $f'(\zeta)$, we use the MVT which tells us that $\zeta \in (a,x)$.

Comment: And another thing: you're right we could write $m_h$ as $g(h)$. But isn't $\lim_{h\to0^+} m_h$ undefined? We need $\lim_{h\to0^-} m_h$

Comment: @politeproofs We are only concerned with the limit of $f'(\zeta)$. This is perfectly well-defined even if $ \zeta \in (a,x)$. If you disagree, please explain why the reasoning I gave fails. The issue is just that you are misinterpreting the limit. As for $m_h$, note that if $h < 0$, we are taking the infimum of an empty set. This is unlikely to be what is intended, which is why I assumed at the start of my answer that $h \ge 0$. I do not see any reason why the limit $h \to 0^+$ would be undefined.

Comment: I disagree, because $(a,a)$ is empty. So no such $\zeta$ exists. As for the other one, I meant to say $h \to 0^-$ would be undefined if we assume $h > 0$.

Comment: @politeproofs And where did I use in my proof that $(a,a)$ is non-empty?

Comment: @politeproofs You are fundamentally misunderstanding the nature of limits. The fact that $(a,a)$ is empty is totally irrelevant to any attempt to prove or disprove this. This is evidenced by the fact that I have given a perfectly valid proof despite your doubts. At no point do we require that $\zeta \in (a,a)$, so at no point is there an issue. There's not really much more I or anyone else could say; you simply need to revise your understanding of limits. (As Lee Mosher said and I have also said, no limits are actually being applied to any intervals.)

Comment: But why don't we care if $\zeta$ could be in an empty set...

Comment: @politeproofs It is not part of the proof. The same reason we don't care for this proof if my watch is broken or platypuses are mammals. *It is not relevant*. Given that you can't actually demonstrate where I used in my proof $\zeta \in (a,a)$, there is nothing left to say. If logical mathematical reasoning is sufficient for you, then read my proof. If it isn't, then no one here will be able to help you. If you want to continue pondering the *completely irrelevant* idea that $\zeta \in (a,a)$, there's nothing else I can do. It doesn't prove or disprove anything; it is *irrelevant*. Goodbye.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but I don't think your attitude was appropriate. Yelling that $\zeta \in (a,x) \to (a,a)$ as $x \to a$ is irrelevant is not quite right since $\zeta \in (a,x)$ by the first line of your proof.

Comment: @politeproofs I don't think your repeated refusal to properly read anything I said was appropriate. Don't accept my answer if you don't want to. As I wrote in my answer the very first time, $\zeta \in (a,x)$ "$\to (a,a)$" (which doesn't even make sense) does not imply $\zeta \in (a,a)$, as you kept on insisting. "Why don't we care if $\zeta$ is in an empty set"? *It never is*, as I repeatedly pointed out to you, and this should be clear to you since you are clearly familiar with the concept of a limit. Try not to force someone to repeat themselves thrice in the future.